# Where to set UITableViewCell's accessibility traits?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiaccessibility

I'm currently setting the accessibility traits of a `UITableViewCell` in its `awakeFromNib()` method and the application is crashing. The code looks like below:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    self.label1.isAccessibilityElement = true
    self.label1.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitButton
    self.label1.accessibilityLabel = selectedAccount.text

    self.label2.isAccessibilityElement = true
    self.label2.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitButton
    self.label2.accessibilityLabel = accountBalance.text
}
```

Should this be set in `cellForRow()` method instead?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally do something like this inside of the UITableViewCells initialisation method to keep it clean:

```
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        // SET UP EVERYTHING IN YOUR CELL HERE.
    }
```